# How can I iterate over a list of strings with ints in python?

Tags: python, variables, loops, int

I'm new to programming with python and programming in general and got stuck wit the following problem:

```
b=["hi","hello","howdy"]
for i in b:
    print i

#This code outputs:
hi
hello
howdy
```

How can I make it so the iterating variable is an int so it works the following way?

```
b=["hi","hello","howdy"]
for i in b:
    print i

#I want it to output:
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pythonic way would be with `enumerate()`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(b):
    print index, item
```

There's also `range(len(b))`, but you almost always will retrieve `item` in the loop body, so `enumerate()` is the better choice most of the time:

```
for index in range(len(b)):
    print index, b[index]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe how long it took me to find this answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
b=["hi","hello","howdy"]
for count,i in enumerate(b):
    print count
```

Answer (score 1):

you could always do this:

```
b=["hi","hello","howdy"]
for i in range(len(b)):
    print i
```