# returning indices using a while loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to take an input of a list of numbers and return the list of indices in the original list that contain negative values.  I also want to use a while loop.  Here is my code so far.

```
def scrollList2(myList):
    negativeIndices = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(myList):
        if myList[i] < 0:
            i = i + 1
            negativeIndices.append(i)
    return negativeIndices
```

How to I stop the loop and how do i get the indices to return?  Right now when I run it, it runs forever (infinite loop)  how do I tell it to stop once it hits the last indices of myList?

Comment: check [enumerate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259627/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-list-of-strings-with-ints-in-python) by the way

Comment: You are only incementing `i` when you see numbers below zero. Any number >= 0 will create an endless loop. Move the increment outside the condition (or better yet, use a `for` loop directly).

Answer (score 2):

When you hit your first non-negative number, the `if` is never entered again and `i` never gets incremented again. Put the part where you increment `i` outside the `if` block.

Comment: I put it after negativeIndices.append(i) and outside the if loop and it just returns [], not a list of the indices when they are negative.

Comment: I tried doing the same and it works just fine. Also, `if` statements are not loops. A loop is something that repeats something.

Comment: I made a mistake, thank you for your help.  I understand it better now.

Answer (score 1):

```
while i < len(myList):
    if myList[i] < 0:
        i = i + 1
        negativeIndices.append(i)
```

Assume, the conditional `myList[i] < 0` is not true. In that case, `i` won’t be incremented and nothing else happens either. So you will end up in the next iteration, with the same value of `i` and the same conditional. Forever, in an endless loop.

You will want to increment `i` regardless of whether you matched something or not. So you will have to put the increment outside of the `if` conditional. Furthermore, you want to increment `i` *after* appending the index to the list, so you actually append the index you tested, and not the one afterwards:

```
while i < len(myList):
    if myList[i] < 0:
        negativeIndices.append(i)
    i = i + 1
```

Also, you would usually use a `for` loop here. It will automatically take care of giving you all the values of `i` which you need to index every element in `myList`. It works like this:

```
negativeIndices = []
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i] < 0:
        negativeIndices.append(i)
```

`range(len(myList))` will give you a sequence of values for every number from zero to the length of the list (not including the length itself). So if your list holds `4` values, you will get the values `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` for `i`. So you won’t need to take care of incrementing it on your own.

Another possibility would be [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) as Foo Bar User mentioned. That function will take a sequence, or list in your case, and will give you both an index and the value at the same time:

```
negativeIndices = []
for i, value in enumerate(myList):
    if value < 0:
        negativeIndices.append(i)
```

As you can see, this completely removes the need to even access the list by its index.

Comment: If abandoning the OP's requirement to use a `while` loop, I'd go with a list comprehension: `[index for (index, value) in enumerate(myLst) if value < 0]`

Answer (score 0):

OP wants to use a while loop, so this answer is not exactly on point - but I feel I should point out that many pythonistas will expect something like:

```
neg_indices = [k for k,v in enumerate(myList) if v < 0]
```

This is implicit in the other answers, however it might be useful for lurkers and for OP to consider down the road...  **While** certainly does the job as the other answers show, but its 'free' in a list comprehension; plus, there's no chance of an infinite loop here....